# Encode a file sign by sign in C

Tags: c

So I have this code to encode a string from a user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char substitute(char letter, char* cipher)
{
    int i;
    int cipher_length = strlen(cipher);
    char substitution = letter;

    for(i = 0; i < cipher_length; ++i)
    {
        if(cipher[i] == letter)
        {
            substitution = cipher[(i%2) ? (i-1) : (i+1)];
            break;
        }
    }
    return substitution;
}

void GaDeRy(char* stringtoencode, char* fullcipher)
 {
     int i;
     char* cipher = fullcipher;
     int string_length = strlen(stringtoencode);

     for(i = 0; i < string_length; ++i)
     {
         stringtoencode[i] = substitute(stringtoencode[i], cipher);
     }
}



int main()
{
    char* cipher1 = "GADERYPOLUKIgaderypoluki";
    char* cipher2 = "POLITYKARENUpolitykarenu";
    char* cipher3 = "KACEMINUTOWYkaceminutowy";

    char stringtoencode[20] = {'0'};
    int option;
    printf("Enter a string that you want to encode:\nMax 20 characters\n");
    scanf("%s", stringtoencode);

    printf("Choose the cipher\n");
    printf("[1]GA-DE-RY-PO-LU-KI\n");
    printf("[2]PO-LI-TY-KA-RE-NU\n");
    printf("[3]KA-CE-MI-NU-TO-WY\n");

    scanf("%d",&option);

    switch(option)
    {
        case 1: GaDeRy(stringtoencode, cipher1 );
            break;
        case 2: GaDeRy(stringtoencode, cipher2 );
            break;
        case 3: GaDeRy(stringtoencode, cipher3 );
            break;
    }
   printf("Encrypted as: %s\n", stringtoencode);
}
```

I have to change it to encode a .txt file sign by sign.
Can I get any help or tips how to it?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I know you haven't, or you would have posted the code here, not on another site.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you asking about how you can read a file in one character at a time, and write a new file that is encoded? What code have you written in your attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: I added `#include <string.h>` and ran your program entering my real name and option 2. It produced an encoding suspiciously close to anagrams of my forename and surname. What is your question?

Comment: If your question is to encode a text file, redirect the input and output of the program, with coding method predetermined.

Comment: What is "sign by sign"?  Do you mean character by character?

Comment: Yep character by character, it has to get the text from file, encode with an anagram chosen by a user and redirect it to output. I just can write a simple program to read  character by character, but I don't know how to implement it here :/

Comment: From a Windows console that would be `myprogram<input.txt>output.txt`.

Comment: I guess you want something like this snippet: while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) putchar(substitute(c, cipher));

Comment: You guessed well, but where to implement it  or how more or less

Comment: We shouldn't have to guess anything. Put it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char substitute(char letter, char* cipher)
{
int i;
int cipher_length = strlen(cipher);
char substitution = letter;

for(i = 0; i < cipher_length; ++i)
{
    if(cipher[i] == letter)
    {
        substitution = cipher[(i%2) ? (i-1) : (i+1)];
        break;
    }
}
return substitution;
}

void GaDeRy(char* stringtoencode, char* fullcipher)
{
 int i;
 char* cipher = fullcipher;
 int string_length = strlen(stringtoencode);
 for(i = 0; i < string_length; ++i)
 {
     stringtoencode[i] = substitute(stringtoencode[i], cipher);
 }
 }

 int main()
{
char c;
int option;
FILE *plik = fopen( "hp.txt", "rt" );
char* cipher1 = "GADERYPOLUKIgaderypoluki";
char* cipher2 = "POLITYKARENUpolitykarenu";
char* cipher3 = "KACEMINUTOWYkaceminutowy"; 

printf("Choose the cipher\n");
printf("[1]GA-DE-RY-PO-LU-KI\n");
printf("[2]PO-LI-TY-KA-RE-NU\n");
printf("[3]KA-CE-MI-NU-TO-WY\n");
scanf("%d",&option);

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
c = getc( plik );
switch(option)
{
    case 1: putchar(substitute(c, cipher1));
        break;
    case 2:  putchar(substitute(c, cipher2));
        break;
    case 3:  putchar(substitute(c, cipher3));
        break;
}
}

fclose( plik );  
}
```

Comment: So I did sth like this, but I need to use an 'enter' key to show the encrypted text. Can someone tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: Okey I changed, while condition to:  while(c != EOF) , and it's working :)
I have last question, how to save an encoded text to a new file ?

Comment: putc(putchar(substitute(c, cipher1)),encoded);   I made this and it works, created new file, everythind :D